# Specify ip and host in ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, dns

For an internal project that I'm working on, I'm making an `$.ajax` call to get data from a different server. My `hosts` file is set up correctly and everything works, but it doesn't for my co-workers because the url doesn't resolve. I can go around and individually fix all their hosts files (or handle the office DNS resolver - but I don't have immediate control over that and it would take a while put push a change through), but I thought there might be a way within the ajax call to specify the ip/host. Essentially specifying the DNS resolution for this call within the request itself.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "a.b.c/blah.aspx",
    ip: "10.10.1.1",
    method: "POST",
    data: myData
}) ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No, there's no way to do this. Alternatively, you can just use `10.10.1.1/blah.aspx` instead of using your vanity URL.

Comment: tried that, but the receiving server needs the host specified to know which apache config to route the call to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifying the ip of the request, then the only reason to also supply the host is to modify the Host header field. A quick google of "ajax request host header" return [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46702/how-can-i-control-the-content-of-the-http-host-header-in-requests-issued-from-my)